# memory allocation eror in C

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been working on the following code for a while and there is a problem when I tried to allocate/deallocate memory for a struct and its elements. Any insights into the problem would be greatly appreciated thanks. Looking at the error message, I believe the problem lies in the fact that I tried to free an element that I had not properly allocated memory for but it is not obvious to me while looking at the code. I also tried code where I did not individually allocate memory for each element of the struct but that did not work as well.

```c
typedef struct {
  char *cnet;
  char *email;
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  char *tel;
} vcard;

vcard *vcard_new(char *cnet, char *email, char *fname, char *lname, char *tel)
{
  vcard* new = (vcard*)malloc(sizeof(vcard));
  printf("%lu\n", sizeof(new->tel) );
  new->cnet = malloc(sizeof(new->cnet));
  new->email = malloc(sizeof(new->email));
  new->fname = malloc(sizeof(new->fname));
  new->lname = malloc(sizeof(new->lname));
  new->tel = malloc(sizeof(new->tel));
  new->cnet = cnet;
  new->email = email;
  new->fname = fname;
  new->lname = lname;
  new->tel = tel;
  return new;
}

/* vcard_free : free vcard and the strings it points to
 */
void vcard_free(vcard *c)
{
  free(c->cnet);
  free(c->email);
  free(c->fname);
  free(c->lname);
  free(c->tel);
  free(c);
  return;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(new->cnet)` = size of a *pointer*, and I seriously suspect that is not intentional. Rinse/repeat for every allocation in that function Not that it matters much, since you leak all of those allocations later in the same function. Assignment operators are not how strings are copied in C; it's how *values* are copied, and in this case, they're the values of pointers. A good C text and the section on strings, followed by the section on dynamic memory, will help immensely.

Comment: This is a C question, but if you ever want to compile your code with a C++ compliler, I would rethink about naming a variable `new` :-).

Answer (score 6):

Your entire memory allocation is erroneous. Here are some pointers.

1. You allocate memory for only one `char *`, which is not what is intended.

   - Lesser memory allocation, possibility of boundary overrun.
2. Then, you overwrite the allocated memory by assigning the parameters to the same variables which held the pointer to allocated memories.

   - You end up causing memory leak.
3. You try to free the pointers which are not returned by `malloc()` and family.

   - Invalid attempt to `free()`, causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
4. You have used wrong format specifier in `printf()`

   - `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`, you must use `%zu` to print the result.

---

Solutions:

1. Allocate enough memory to store the expected content, like in predefined sizes

   ```
    #define CNETSIZ 32
    #define EMAILSIZ 64
    . . . . . 
    new->cnet = malloc(CNETSIZ);
    new->email = malloc(EMAILSIZ);
   ```

   or, based on the length of the input string, like

   ```
    new->cnet = malloc(strlen(cnet)+1);  //+1 for the space to null-terminator
   ```
2. Inside the `vcard_new()` function, use `strcpy()` to copy the content from the function parameters, like

   ```
   strcpy(new->cnet, cnet);
   strcpy(new->email, email);
   ```

Comment: Recommended: avoid use of the English word 'pointer' for something other than what it means in C. Choose from the many available synonyms...

Comment: @machine_1 That's _punny_. :)

Answer (score 4):

You're just allocating enough memory to hold another `char*` instead of the actual string. And then you overwrite the pointer with the pointer passed. Later you try to free that pointer, which means that it will try to free the memory of which you took a pointer and passed it to the function. Instead you should do this:

```
vcard *vcard_new(char *cnet, char *email, char *fname, char *lname, char *tel)
{
  vcard* new = (vcard*)malloc(sizeof(vcard));
  new->cnet = malloc(strlen(cnet)+1);
  strcpy(new->cnet, cnet);
  ...
}
```

Or, if [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) is available on your system:

```
vcard *vcard_new(char *cnet, char *email, char *fname, char *lname, char *tel)
{
  vcard* new = (vcard*)malloc(sizeof(vcard));
  new->cnet = strdup(cnet);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It all works now.

Answer (score 3):

Using  `new->cnet = malloc(sizeof(new->cnet))`  you are allocating an amount of memory for cnet string equals to the pointer size and not to the actual string length.